# Extjs 6 system wide ajax callback

Tags: ajax, extjs6

Is there some way to implement a kind of `beforeLoad` and `afterLoad` for all `Ext.Ajax.request` at same central piece of code (unique callback function)?

I want to display and hide a `Waiting...` icon on all my requests ("solo" ajax and store loads) and don't want to rewrite code on every one.

Answer (score 0):

The Ext.Ajax is a singleton. What you can do is make your own Ext.AjaxOfMyOwn class that extends the Ext.Ajax singleton.

Instead of the Ext.Ajax singleton your app is application wide using your own developed Ext.Ajax.. class. In that class of your own your event functions based on the existing ones.

When you place in your rewritten event functions 'this.callParent()' it will execute also the code from the class where it has been extended from, that is Ext.Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Put this in Application's launch function

```
launch: function () {

  Ext.Ajax.on("beforerequest", function (conn, options, eOpts) {
     console.log( options );
  }

}
```

Seems to be system wide for all ajax requests.... will see.
Ref: [how to add beforerequest event to ajax request in Extjs 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198551/how-to-add-beforerequest-event-to-ajax-request-in-extjs-4)

Comment: Working as I want. Including Store calls !